# Implementing a Graph using a HashMap

Tags: java, graph

I'm new to Java, so please keep that in mind before getting trigger happy down-voting. I'm familiar with the popular implementation of a graph of integers using an array.

```
Graph{
 int vertices;
 LinkedList<Integer>[] adj;

Graph(int vertices){
   this.vertices = vertices;
   adj = new LinkedList<>();
   for(int i= 0; i <vertices; i++){
      adj[i] = new LinkedList(); 
   }
}
```

However this implementation is best suited to a graph of integers.
In case I want to implmentation graph of Characters, this implemetation doesn't render itself directly usable.
So I tried implementing using a HashMap.

```
public class Graph {
    int vertices;
    HashMap<Character, LinkedList<Character>> adj;


    Graph(int item){

       this.vertices = item;
       adj = new HashMap<>();

    }
}
```

Where I'm a little stuck syntactically with Java is adding keys and values to this HashTable. What I'm trying to do is implement this method.

```
public void add(Character a, Character b){

            if (adj.containsKey(a)){

               //get a reference to the existing linked list
               //add to the existing LinkedList
            }else{

               //create a new LinkedList and add to it.
            }

        }
    }
```

I could use some help with the incomplete add method as also how to iterate through the this adj HashMap once the graph is constructed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your question is only about syntax, you can do something like this:

```
public void add(Character a, Character b){

        if (adj.containsKey(a)){

           //get a reference to the existing linked list
           LinkedList<Character> l = adj.get(a);

           //add to the existing LinkedList
           //You need to do a null check here to make sure (l != null)
           l.add(b)
        }else{

           //create a new LinkedList and add to it.
           LinkedList<Character> l = new LinkedList<Character>();
           l.add(b);
           adj.put(a, l);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`HashMap` stores the node number as key and the list of all the adjacent nodes as value. The list has been implemented using `LinkedList class`. Just change the class of Key and value according to your requirement.

```
class Graph{
HashMap<Integer,LinkedList<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();

//add an edge from source to destination
void addEdge(int src, int dest){
    if(!map.containsKey(src)){
        LinkedList<Integer> l= new LinkedList<>();
        l.add(dest);
        map.put(src,l);
    }

    else{
        LinkedList<Integer> l= map.get(src);
        l.add(dest);
        map.put(src,l);
    }
}

//display the adjency list
void displayGraph(){
    for(Map.Entry m: map.entrySet()){
        System.out.println(m.getKey()+"-->"+m.getValue());
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Graph g= new Graph();
    g.addEdge(0,1);
    g.addEdge(0,4);
    g.addEdge(0,5);
    g.addEdge(1,4);
    g.addEdge(1,3);
    g.addEdge(3,2);
    g.addEdge(2,1);
    g.addEdge(3,4);
    g.displayGraph();
}
}
```

Output:

```
  0-->[1, 4, 5]
  1-->[4, 3]
  2-->[1]
  3-->[2, 4]
```